# Method filter does not exist when updating from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to update from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2. `composer update` ran succesfully. Here is my composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
    "vinkla/hashids": "^2.2",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "~2.0.1",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1",
    "robclancy/presenter": "1.3.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.2",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.2.8",
    "league/fractal": "^0.12.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "~2.8",
    "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "~5.1",
    "torann/geoip": "0.2.*@dev",
    "mailchimp/mailchimp": "^2.0",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "~2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "~1.3",
    "sybio/gif-frame-extractor": "^1.0",
    "coldume/imagecraft": "dev-gif-optimization",
    "pragmarx/firewall": "^0.5.2",
    "get-stream/stream-laravel": "dev-master",
    "roumen/sitemap": "2.5.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "1.*",
    "cviebrock/image-validator": "^2.0",
    "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
    "embedly/embedly-php": "0.5.*",
    "facebook/webdriver": "^1.0",
    "scotteh/php-dom-wrapper": "dev-composer-symfony-fix",
    "scotteh/php-goose": "dev-composer-guzzle-fix",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/imagecraft"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/php-goose"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/zmike808GS/php-dom-wrapper"
    }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Garagesocial\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "github-oauth": {
      "github.com": "e0530adb37eea46a185bdfc096bc709d842471fe"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when it launches `php artisan clear-compiled` the following error appears:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Method filter does not exist.
```

Without any further information. As I understand, filter was deprecated, but I do not use filters in my `routes.php`. If I try to load any page, here is the exception I am getting:

```
    BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
    Method filter does not exist.


    in Macroable.php line 74
    at Router->__call('filter', array('fw-block-bl', '\PragmaRX\Firewall\Filters\Blacklist')) in ServiceProvider.php line 163
    at Router->filter('fw-block-bl', '\PragmaRX\Firewall\Filters\Blacklist') in ServiceProvider.php line 163
    at ServiceProvider->registerFilters() in ServiceProvider.php line 67
    at ServiceProvider->register() in Application.php line 554
    at Application->register(object(ServiceProvider)) in ProviderRepository.php line 74
    at ProviderRepository->load(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\BusServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\RouteServiceProvider', 'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider', 'Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider', 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider', 'Baum\Providers\BaumServiceProvider', 'Robbo\Presenter\PresenterServiceProvider', 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider', 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider', 'Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider', 'Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider', 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Storage\FluentStorageServiceProvider', 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider', 'Roumen\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider', 'GetStream\StreamLaravel\StreamLaravelServiceProvider', 'Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\BugsnagLaravelServiceProvider', 'Cviebrock\ImageValidator\ImageValidatorServiceProvider', 'Toin0u\Geocoder\GeocoderServiceProvider', 'PragmaRX\Firewall\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\MailerServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\Headers\HeadersModelServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\Factories\GenappFactoryServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\Factories\ObjectFactoryServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\Factories\HeaderFactoryServiceProvider', 'Garagesocial\Providers\Factories\TransformerFactoryServiceProvider')) in Application.php line 530
    at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 17
    at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
    at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 232
    at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 127
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 65
```

Could you please help me to get rid of this error? All the stack trace references the internal files which I do not want to edit manually, and I am not sure how to fix that

Comment: Did you try to empty the bootstrap cache manually?

Comment: @JoelHinz Now I did and that did not help

Comment: Seems like you're using an old version of pragmarx/firewall that did use filters. The newest version (1.0.3) does not. The package author, @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, is quite active on StackOverflow if you need help.

Comment: @JoelHinz That helped, thanks

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. :)